# request and response objects in servlet

Tags: java, jsp

Generally speaking, we have request and response objects in a servlet. A response is used to send data back to the client, while we request fetches the data from the client. How come response.sendredirect and request.getRequestDispatcher, or set on different objects, if they in reality or the same (except for the fact that you also forward the request and response objects using the request dispatcher)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; how are `sendRedirect` and `getRequestDispatcher` the same thing? Sending a redirect is a response back to the browser telling it to make a new request. A request dispatcher determines how a request is handled (e.g., forward or include).

Comment: Okay thank you @DaveNewton

Comment: But is it correct to say that generally, the request object is the data sent from the user, while the response object is the, is the data sent back to the user?

Comment: Yes; browser makes a request and gets a response, just like any other conversation. There's no "generally" about it.

Comment: Its very common for the server to add data to the request. It all depends on how your code is written but, lots of stuff can be added. Personally, I tend to pass along user/security data from filters.